# Scp'ing from remote server to local server

Tags: cluster-computing, scp

Currently, I am trying to scp from a remote server (a computer cluster) to my local MAC OSX. However, whenever I try to send a file from the cluster to my computer, I get this error.

```
ssh: connect to host 73.232.71.182 port 22: Connection timed out
lost connection
```

Ssh is installed correctly and which scp gives the desired output and this is the output of ssh -v localhost.

```
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /s1/snagaraj/.ssh/config
debug1: /s1/snagaraj/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 73.232.71.182 [73.232.71.182] port 22.

debug1: connect to address 73.232.71.182 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 73.232.71.182 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Edit 1: What would you want me to check? Ping seems to work and the traceroute command works (but I do not want to reveal the output as it shows where I live).

Comment: This sounds like a network filtering issue. Maybe your client machine is doing outbound filtering to port 22, or the host's firewall needs to be configured to accept connections from your IP address. I'd suggest trying a `ping 73.232.71.182` or a `traceroute 73.232.71.182` to see if the host is at all reachable.

Comment: When I use a ping/traceroute from the remote cluster to my local computer ip, the ping goes through. Additionally, pinging my remote cluster from my local computer works.

Comment: Have you tried `tcpdump` or a similar traffic analyser to see what is actually sent and received over the wire? Can you reach other ports on the host machine? If possible, you might want to contact the host's network administrator to ask if any filtering is done.

Comment: I do not have access to use tcpdump.

Comment: Contact the host administrator for support.